# Comprehension of Actor with ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, akka, executioncontext

As I understand Akka parallelism, to handle each incoming message Actor use one thread. And this thread contains one state. As is it so, sequential messages does't share this states.

But Actor may have an ExecutorContext for execute callbacks from Future. And this is the point, where I stop understanding parallelism clearly.

For example we have the following actor:

```
  class AnyActor(target: ActorRef) extends Actor { 
          implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

          def receive = {
               case messageA =>
                    val api = createApi()
                    val furureA: Future[F] = api.callA 
                        api.close()
                    futureA.pipeTo(sender()) 
               case messageB =>
                    val api = createApi()
                    val furureB: Future[F] = api.callB 
                        api.close()
                    futureB.pipeTo(sender()) 
             }
  }
```

Suppose, Actor receive messageA, and Thread1 create instance of api - let 's call "api1". Also there is executionContext with N of threads. One of this threads is used for retrieve result from furureA.

What I don't understand, is how this N threads correlate with Thread1.    ExecutionContext is created only for Thread1?  Or it is also created for Thread2 (in which messageB handled)?

Comment: Sorry just to be clear. Are you saying each Actor allocates a unique thread? Because that is definitely not true (might be true for some absurd execution context but I don't think the default acts that way). Actors are meant to act as a lightweight threads. If each allocated a thread that would destroy the JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly, actors run on an dispatcher which selects a thread from a pool and runs that actor's `Receive` for some number of messages from the mailbox.  There is no guarantee in general that an actor will run on a given thread (ignoring vacuous examples like a pool with a single thread, or a dispatcher which always runs a given actor in a specific thread).

That dispatcher is also a Scala `ExecutionContext` which allows arbitrary tasks to be scheduled for execution on its thread pool; such tasks include `Future` callbacks.

So in your actor, what happens when a `messageA` is received?

- The actor calls `createApi()` and saves it
- It calls the `callA` method on `api`
- It closes `api`
- It arranges to forward the result of `callA` when it's available to the sender
- It is now ready to process another message and may or may not actually process another message

What this actually means depends on what `callA` does.  If `callA` schedules a task on the execution context, it will return the future as soon as the task is scheduled and the callbacks have been arranged; there is no guarantee that the task or callbacks have been executed when the future is returned.  As soon as the future is returned, your actor closes `api` (so this might happen at any point in the task's or callbacks' execution).

In short, depending on how `api` is implemented (and you might not have control over how it's implemented) and on the implementation details, the following ordering is possible

- Thread1 (processing `messageA`) sets up tasks in the dispatcher
- Thread1 closes `api` and arranges for the result to be piped
- Thread2 starts executing task
- Thread1 moves on to processing some other message
- Thread2's task fails because `api` has been closed

In short, when mixing `Future`s and actors, the "single-threaded illusion" in Akka can be broken: it becomes possible for arbitrarily many threads to manipulate the actor's state.

In this example, because the only shared state between `Future`land and actorland is local to the processing of a single message, it's not that bad: the general rule in force here is:

- As soon as you hand mutable (e.g. closeable) state from an actor to a future (this includes, unless you can be absolutely sure what's happening, calling a method on that stateful object which returns a future), it's best for the actor to forget about the existence of that object

How then to close `api`?

Well, assuming that `callA` isn't doing anything funky with `api` (like saving the instance in some pool of instances), after `messageA` is done processing and the future is completed, nothing has access to `api`.  So the simplest, and likely most correct, thing to do is arrange for `api` to be closed after the future has completed, along these lines

```scala
val api = createApi()
val futureA: Future[F] = api.callA

futureA.foreach { _ => api.close() }
futureA.pipeTo(sender())
```

Comment: Shorter answer to your question is that the future could run on any of the N threads, including Thread1 (it could only run on Thread1 after the messages have been processed).

Comment: Levi Ramsey, its a great and exhaustive answer! But I have one more clarification. Assume, 2 sequential messageA received in time interval.  Is it possible the following order (if api closed after future completed):  1. Thread1 sets up task for message1. 2. In Thread2 actor receive message2. 3. Future completed for message1-callback. 4. Thread1 close api  4. Thread2 tried to call api for message2,  but failed, as api closed.      ????

Comment: Each time the actor gets `messageA`, it's apparently creating a new api, so the closure shouldn't affect the subsequent message

Comment: Thank you! I suspected it, but decided to clarify additionally